# Calculate 3D point coordinates using horizontal and vertical angles and slope distance

Tags: 3d, coordinates, trigonometry

I am trying to learn how to calculate the XYZ coordinates of a point using the XYZ coordinates of an origin point, a horizontal and vertical angle, and 3d distance.  I can make the calculations simply by projecting the points onto 2D planes, but is there a more straightforward way to do this in 3D?

I am trying to understand how a surveying total station calculates new point locations based on it's measured location, the 3d (slope) distance that it measures to a new point, and the measured horizontal and vertical angles that sight onto the new point location.

Thanks,

E

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates?

Answer (score 14):

Just a note on conventions: [2D polar coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html) often use `(radius, theta)`, where `theta` is the 'horizontal' or 'azimuth' angle. It ranges from: `theta=0`, the 2D point `(x,y) = (radius,0)` on the X-axis, to: `theta=2*PI` on the XY plane - an anti-clockwise direction as `theta` increases. Now to confuse matters...

[3D spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (maintaining a right-handed coordinate system) often use coordinates: `(radius, theta, phi)`. In this case, `theta` is used for the 'vertical' or 'zenith' angle, ranging from `theta=0` (the Z axis) to `theta=PI` (the -Z axis). `phi` is used for the azimuth angle.

Other texts will use different conventions - but this seems to be favoured by physicists and (some) mathematics texts. *What matters is that you pick a convention and use it consistently*.

**Following this:**

*`radius`*: distance to the point. given an point `(x,y,z)` in cartesian coordinates, we have the (pythagorean) radius: `r = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)`, e.g., **`0 <= radius < +infinity`**

*`theta`*: the zenith angle, where `theta=0` is directly above (the +Z axis), and `theta=PI` is directly below (the -Z axis), and `theta=PI/2` is what you would consider an 'elevation' of 0 degrees, e.g.,
**`0 <= theta <= PI`**

*`phi`*: the azimuth angle, where `phi=0` is to the 'right' (the +X axis), and as you turn 'anticlockwise', `phi=PI/2` (the +Y axis), `phi=PI` (the -X axis), `phi=3*PI/2` (the -Y axis), and `phi=2*PI` - equivalent to the `phi=0` (back to the +X axis). e.g., **`0 <= phi < 2*PI`**

---

**Pseudo-code:** (standard math library trigonometric functions)

From `(radius, theta, phi)` you can find the point `(x,y,z)` :

`x = radius * sin(theta) * cos(phi);`
`y = radius * sin(theta) * sin(phi);`
`z = radius * cos(theta);`

Conversely, you can find a `(radius, theta, phi)` *from* `(x,y,z)` :

`radius = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);`
`theta  = acos(z / radius);`
`phi    = atan2(y, x);`

Note: it is important to use [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) in the final equation, *not* `atan`!

Comment: My hero - I was looking for this.

Answer (score -1):

Previous answer is almost perfect, just in the pseudo code, one of the sin should be a cos:

```
X = radius * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
y = radius * cos(theta) * sin(phi);
z = radius * cos(theta);
```

Comment: `theta` is the inclination angle in this [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)  - not the `azimuth` angle used in polar coordinates.