# 3D Vector coordinates from x and y rotation

Tags: math, vector, 3d

I tried to google this question several times, but i found only articles about "Rotation matrix".

[image]

I have 3d coordinate system and two angles: `α` for x-rotation and `β` for y-rotation (I'm not sure if I've positioned the angles correctly in the diagram).

And i need to find coordinates of `Vector(x_1, y_1, z_1)`

Please, help me to figure out the formulas.

Comment: So you're trying to rotate a vector(x,y,z) around the x and y axes with angles alpha and beta? I'm just trying to understand your desired inputs and outputs

Comment: i want to find coordinates of this vector. at the beginning of program, angles are ```x = 0``` and ```y = 0```

Comment: Yes but what vector? It looks like you're starting with a unit vector at (x,y,z) => (1,0,0) and transforming it by rotating beta radians counter-clockwise around the z-axis and then rotating alpha radians clockwise around the y-axis. Is that correct?

Comment: i guess, alpha angle is misplaced, so vector have coordinates ```(0, 0, 1)```

Comment: But alpha is a rotation about the y-axis and beta is a rotation about the z-axis?

Comment: i fixed diagram. now all angles should be placed correctly

Comment: I see your updated diagram. Technicalities aside, I understand what you mean now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate 3D point coordinates using horizontal and vertical angles and slope distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619901/calculate-3d-point-coordinates-using-horizontal-and-vertical-angles-and-slope-di)

Comment: no that's a slightly different question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be posted on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you! I'll ask all math questions on math.stackexchange.com next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this up into two transformations.

Starting with your unit vector at (0,0,1), we'll apply the alpha transformation first.

[image]

You can treat the rotation about the y-axis as a 2-D transformation and ignore the y-axis entirely. Then it becomes simple trig to get the x and z components with cos and sin of your transformation angle (alpha). We know the length of the vector is 1 since it's a unit vector, but your vector could be any length -- just multiply the cos and sin equations by the length of your vector.

This first transformation leaves us with this formula:

`(x1, y, z1) => (sin(alpha), 0, cos(alpha))`

Assume your transformation angle starts on the +z axis and as it increases, the angle moves counterclockwise around the y-axis (or on the XZ plane).

For the second transformation, We're rotating around the axis perpendicular to our vector. We will do something very similar, but this time substituting x1 and z1 for our new values sin(alpha) and cos(alpha).

Getting y1 is as simple as taking the sin of your beta angle like before, but transforming x1 and z1 requires us to scale x1 and z1 by the cosine component of this triangle. This is because the relationship between x1 and z1 does not change as we rotate around their perpendicular axis.

Imagine a circle with the center at the origin and a single point on its circumference at (x1, 0, z1). As we rotate the vector around that circle, x1 and z1 scale relative to the center point, but their ratio does not change.

[image]

All we have to do is scale both numbers by the cosine component of our beta angle. I labeled that omega here.

[image]

This leaves us with a final formula of

`(x2, y1, z2) => (cos(beta)*sin(alpha), sin(beta), cos(beta)*cos(alpha))`

Comment: i can't understand, what i do wrong. i just add direction vector to my position: `camera = camera + dir` and it works strange. [this is how it works](https://youtu.be/uGURljJJ_Cc)

This is how i use it:
`float alpha = theta.x;
 float beta = theta.y;
 Vector dir(cos(beta)*sin(alpha), sin(beta), cos(beta)*cos(alpha));
 camera = camera + dir;
`

Comment: The Z component of your forward vector is not changing. Can you show me your code implementation? Also at this rate, you could probably just the camera's forward vector.

Comment: If you can, show where theta is coming from, and also what is setting that X, Y, and Z in the top left corner.

Comment: [this is my full code](https://pastebin.com/LgDuVKqr)

Comment: also i dont use z component, so it is always 0

Comment: Why is your dx measuring your change in mouseY and dy your change in mouseX?

Comment: THANK YOU! i figured out my problem. i missed with coordinates. [now it works perfectely](https://youtu.be/iTODpwPBLUY)